# android onActivityResult and onCreate

Tags: android, oncreate, onactivityresult, appcompatactivity

I want to know whether onCreate always run at first ?

Because in my app, I must set some values in onCreate at first then use them in onActivityResult.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.Please explain it clearly that you want to know!!

Comment: Just tell me the priority of onCreate and onActivityResult , which one runs first .. tnx

Comment: in what context? what research did you do?

Comment: I beleive the question could be rephrased as: "For the same class: is onCreate called when onActivityResult is called, and in that case before or after onActivityResult." I think it is a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

onCreate will always run at some point, but not always immediately before onActivityResult. If the activity has not been destroyed, then onCreate will not be called again before onActivityResult. According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) this method is called just before onResume.